# To be, or not to be - What is the question?

Tags: cipher, english

I just wanted to test my encryption skills with this wonderful community that seems to be able to crack almost any code! I've made a few codes before, but almost always, they were encoded several times over, sometimes in several different languages, and not meant to be decoded by anyone but the recipient. This is a new style of encryption for me - making a code that is meant to be hard, but not unsolvable, so please excuse me if it is too hard or too easy. Anyway, here goes.

The encrypted string to solve is

> **1jz1hy2rpukx1rw2bkv1trlu**

Hint 1:

> Encrypted with the exact same encryption as the one above, the phrase "*How are you today, friend?*" results in **1ydz2ky2bx2hlbw2nkrlv**.

Hint 2:

> In addition, the phrase "*What does the fox say?*" results in **1dyhz2ljy1hyx1ncw1jbv**

Hint 3:

> You guys seem to be having some trouble. "*Black baboons like butter.*" enciphers to **1puevz3pprjy2uvx2phhkw**.

Note: Proper spelin is the key to solving this problem. If you mess up your spelling, you likely won't get anywhere.

Also, the first paragraph legitimately has nothing to do with solving the encryption.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! While you are waiting for the solution, look around, and check out a few resources [tour](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour), [What is a good puzzle?](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/3138/29343).

Comment: @Matsmath I have, in fact, read those already, but thanks.

Comment: @Saiid Add some more examples, please.

Comment: @TheBitByte if nobody has made headway in 3 hours, marking 6 hours after I posted it, I will add another example

Comment: @Saiid Just add all the examples now.

Comment: @TheBitByte I feel that making and adding several new examples would make it a lot easier to solve. However, for the sake of encouraging responses, i will encrypt and add another sentence

Comment: For your cipher to not be too broad, you do need some more examples. If this makes your cipher easier, that is an issue, yes, but you'll still need more example somehow, to make the question less broad.

Comment: @TheBitByte I added another example

Comment: @Saiid In my opinion, only two examples is a bit low. Just add enough examples altogether.

Comment: @TheBitByte You never know, some people are extraordinary cryptologists. If 24 hours goes by since the original post, or if more than one other user requests more, I will add more.

Comment: @Saiid Don't make your puzzle interactive in this way. Just post all examples that you can post, in one go.

Comment: @TheBitByte Also, most puzzles I've seen on here similar to this only give one example.

Comment: @TheBitByte Thanks for expressing your opinion regarding examples. It seems that Saiid has also expressed an opinion, and that the two of you differ. Let's agree to disagree. Note that this is *not* a semi-interactive puzzle, since everything required to solve the puzzle is already here. If Saiid chooses to post more or less examples, that is their prerogative. You may certainly *request* something of them, but please refrain from *demanding* or *commanding*.

Comment: Some first observations: Numbers (`1`, `2`) in the ciphertext seem to indicate the start of a word in the plaintext. If the number is `1`, the letters between this `1` (excluding) and the next number represent the word (e.g. `How` -> `1ydz`). If the number is `2` the letter between this `2` (including) and the next number represent the word (e.g. `are` -> `2ky`). If this is correct, it indicates that the cipher ignores every character except the ones in the standard latin alphabet, so it is not a cipher dealing with bytes, but rather a classical one.

Comment: It's also remarkable that every cipher-word (like I explained in my comment above) ends with the same letter the other ciphertexts do. So the pattern for the last letter always seems to be `z` -> `y` -> `x` -> `w` -> `v` -> `u` -> [...], i.e. most likely reversed alphabet.;

Comment: It seems that the digit always gives the number of vocals in the word.

Comment: It seems to be a substitution cipher on the consonants, and somehow related to the reversed alphabet, but not exactly.

Comment: "Proper spelin" LOL!!

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος yup lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EDITED to fix some mistakes]

I think the decoded message is probably

> IS IT NOBLER IN YOUR MIND

given the title of the puzzle, though it's ambiguous and other readings are possible. Most of what I'm about to say is found in comments on the question, but no one's actually given an answer so I might as well :-).

(I suffered a little because of the ambiguity, which is a little outrageous, but fortunately I was able to find what I'm pretty sure was the right decoding and put an end to my troubles.)

So, each word

> turns into a number followed by some letters.

The number indicates

> the number of vowels in the word (Y is not a vowel for this purpose). There is no further information about what or where the vowels are, hence the ambiguity.

The letters encode

> the consonants, in order, according to a simple substitution cipher.

The cipher

> is constructed in the traditional sort of way where letters in the early part of the alphabet translate to letters of a keyword (duplicates removed) and after that we traverse the alphabet in order, though slightly unusually the order here is reversed.

Specifically,

> the key is ?PEL?N, which is presumably SPELIN as the question actually tells us, and after that the letters go ZY??VU?R???KJH??DCB? which nicely matches reverse order starting with Z. Of course we can never know for sure what the vowels are meant to map to, since they are never actually mapped to anything.

So our message decodes as

> [1]S [1]T [2]NBLR [1]N [2]YR [1]MND

and

> there are many possibilities for all of the words but the one I gave above seems to fit best.